# Add to list the first type missing objects from list the second type

Tags: c#

I have two lists different types. The first list is type of below class:

```
public partial class PersonOneProductOne
{
    public int PersonOneId { get; set; }
    public int ProductOneId { get; set; }
}
```

The second list is type of below class:

```
public partial class PersonTwoProductTwo
{
    public int PersonTwoId { get; set; }
    public int ProductTwoId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add to list type of PersonOneProductOne missing objects from list type of PersonTwoProductTwo but unfortunatelly it isn't so easy because I have also lists how to map PersonOneId and ProductOneId from PersonOneProductOne class to PersonTwoId and ProductTwoId in PersonTwoProductTwo class:

```
public class PersonOnePersonTwo
{
    public int PersonOneId { get; set; } 
    public int PersonTwoId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductOneProductTwo
{
    public int ProductOneId { get; set; }
    public int ProductTwoId { get; set; }
}
```

I have written below code but it is slow, is better way??

```
// data:
List<PersonOneProductOne> personOneProductOneList = new List<PersonOneProductOne>();
List<PersonTwoProductTwo> personTwoProductTwoList = new List<PersonTwoProductTwo>();

// how to map:
List<PersonOnePersonTwo> personOnePersonTwoMapping = new List<PersonOnePersonTwo>();
List<ProductOneProductTwo> productOneProductTwoMapping = new List<ProductOneProductTwo>();

// my algorithm which is slow:
foreach (PersonTwoProductTwo personTwoProductTwo in personTwoProductTwoList)
{
    PersonOnePersonTwo personOnePersonTwo = personOnePersonTwoMapping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonTwoId == personTwoProductTwo.PersonTwoId);
    ProductOneProductTwo productOneProductTwo = productOneProductTwoMapping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductTwoId == personTwoProductTwo.ProductTwoId);

    if (personOnePersonTwo != null && productOneProductTwo != null)
    {
        PersonOneProductOne personOneProductOne = personOneProductOneList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonOneId == personOnePersonTwo.PersonOneId && x.ProductOneId == productOneProductTwo.ProductOneId);

        if (personOneProductOne == null)
        {
            personOneProductOneList.Add(new PersonOneProductOne
                {
                    PersonOneId = personOnePersonTwo.PersonOneId,
                    ProductOneId = productOneProductTwo.ProductOneId
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't figured out how what you are doing makes sense, but for mapping (i.e. your `ProductOneProductTwo` and `PersonOnePersonTwo`), use a `Dictionary` with O(1) lookup time, instead of a list that you search with `FirstOrDefault` with O(N) lookup time.

Answer (score 1):

The code fragment below is not going to speed up your query. It is a translation of your current logic into a single LINQ query. I included it, because it makes your current logic a lot easier to follow (i.e. it is more readable), which is always a good starting point when attempting an optimization.

```
var result = 
    from person2product2 in personTwoProductTwoList
    from person1person2 in personOnePersonTwoMapping
    from product1product2 in productOneProductTwoMapping
    where person2product2.PersonTwoId == person1person2.PersonTwoId &&
          person2product2.ProductTwoId == product1product2.ProductTwoId &&
          !personOneProductOneList.Any(x =>
              x.PersonOneId == person1person2.PersonOneId &&
              x.ProductOneId == product1product2.ProductOneId)
    select new PersonOneProductOne {
        PersonOneId = person1person2.PersonOneId,
        ProductOneId = product1product2.ProductOneId
    };

personOneProductOneList.AddRange(result);
```

An obvious thing that could be optimized, is to use use dictionaries with O(1) lookup time instead of your "mapping" lists, that will have O(N) lookup time.

When using dictionaries **and assuming each person id and product id has an entry**, this could then be transformed into:

```
// Maps PersonTwoId (key) to PersonOneId (value)
Dictionary<int, int> personTwoPersonOneMapping;

// Maps ProductTwoId (key) to ProductOneId (value)
Dictionary<int, int> productTwoProductOneMapping;

var result = 
    from person2product2 in personTwoProductTwoList
    where !personOneProductOneList.Any(x =>
        x.PersonOneId == personTwoPersonOneMapping[person2product2.PersonTwoId] &&
        x.ProductOneId == productTwoProductOneMapping[person2product2.ProductTwoId])
    select new PersonOneProductOne {
        PersonOneId = personTwoPersonOneMapping[person2product2.PersonTwoId],
        ProductOneId = productTwoProductOneMapping[person2product2.ProductTwoId]
    };
```